# AWS Codedeploy: On multiple instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

Ques 1: I'm a new to codedeploy, I plan to deploy different services (S1 , S2 and S3) in order to a different instance under (EC1, EC2 and EC3) under one development Group. And all the services S1, S2 and S3 are present under same artifact directory on S3 bucket.  Is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, you'll want 3 Codedeploy Applications, which will create 3 deployment groups. When it's time for deployment, it will ask for 
 a specific s3 object,the artifact, to deploy.

Start here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/applications.html

CLI example of pushing an app revision

```
aws deploy push \
  --application-name WordPress_App \
  --description "This is a revision for the application WordPress_App" \
  --ignore-hidden-files \
  --s3-location s3://codedeploydemobucket/WordPressApp.zip \
  --source .
```

Comment: So does it mean I want to create 3 applications with individual appsec.yml file ? Is there any way to use single codedeploy application to process different services ?

Comment: Yes to your first, and why would you want to do that to your second?